# M2.2: On the admin side, when an admin modifies the price, how to get warning message what if he set price below $100

Tags: magento2.2, event-observer, price, admin-panel

When an admin is about to modify the price and save the modification, he should get warning message which he should set a price over $100 and it must not be saved what if he set the price below $100.

Is there any basic function on Magento? Or i can use Observer in admin page.

Please give me an idea for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to create basic module in magento2, here I am giving you an idea.

You need to create `event.xml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create your observer file `Productsaveafter.php` at below path -

```
app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\
```

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

```
class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $price = $_product->getPrice(); // will get price
        if($price < 100)
        {
           // put your logic here
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! I created tiny and cute observer referring to your reply!

Comment: Sounds cute @3CE, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Shashank Kumrawat.

This is my code

> app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\etc\adminhtml\event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

   <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
       <observer name="productsaveafter" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
   </event>


</config>
```

> app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Observer\Productsaveafter.php

```
namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Observer;

class Productsaveafter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
    $producType = $_product->getTypeId();
    $price = $_product->getPrice(); // will get price

    if($_producType=="simple" && $price < 100)
        {

            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException(__("Prices have been changed below 100!"));
        }

     return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so getting any issue ?

Comment: Nothing! Perfect working!

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Btw after inserting this code, the loading time of product grid is extremely slow. Do you know what happened to it?

Comment: where are you applying this code?

Comment: are you sure product grid at admin is slow due to above code ? because above code run only on `product_save` observer then it redirects to grid page with displaying your error msg. thus grid page should not get affected with this.

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Ok! Let me make sure it from my end! Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you but it should be adjusted to simple product. I set the code like above but product_type couldn't be configured. Do you know what should i do?  I tested throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException(__('Prices have been changed below 30! "%1"'),$producType); but no value on product type.

Comment: Resolved : It should be `$producType = $_product->getTypeId();` not `$producType = $_product->getProductType();`